# Anagrammatically speaking

Tags: wordplay, anagram

Fill in the blanks below. Each sentence uses words that are anagrams of each other. In each pair of sentences, solve the first sentence, change one letter of an answer-word from that sentence, and shuffle it to form the answer-words for the second sentence. The answer-words in each pair of sentences are the same length or longer as those in the previous pair of sentences. Other than that, there is no correlation between words from one sentence-pair to the next. All resulting sentences must make sense, and must use answer-words that are legal in Scrabble.

For example:

> Mount the ______ sign onto the ______.
>   The fifty ______ coin features the first president in a confident ______.

Answer to the above:

> Mount the STOP sign onto the POST.
>  The fifty PESO coin features the first president in a confident POSE.
>
>  (STOP and POST are anagrams. Change one letter from STOP or POST. In this case, change T to E. Shuffle the result to form PESO and POSE, which are anagrams)

**Update:** The correct answers are distributed among three players' responses, so I am putting the answers inline here to make them easier to find.

Pair 1:

> A few beers ______ ______ my reasoning.
>   The ______ thought the baby was ugly, but she didn’t say so ______.

Answer to the above:

> could, cloud
>  doula, aloud

Pair 2:

> I used to wear polyester ______, but they made me ______, so I switched to cotton.
>   The cats would ______ around the ceramics factory, but not when the ______ were fired up.

Answer to the above:

> knits, stink
>  slink, kilns

Pair 3:

> The man ______ for gold and put the nuggets in a ______ sack.
>   He made one too many ______ comments, and now he ______ alone.

Answer to the above:

> mined, denim
>  snide, dines

Pair 4:

> The biggest ______ in that ______ is the thorns.
>   The lot has ______ parking, but make sure you ______ a permit from your rear-view mirror.

Answer to the above:

> danger, garden
>  angled, dangle

Pair 5:

> He ______ in the most ______ part of town, although he could barely afford it.
>   Whenever she ______ the slippery driveway, I go out and spread some ______ on it.

Answer to the above:

> resided, desired
>  decries, deicers

Pair 6:

> The ______ of the quarry workers decided to block the boss’s car by putting several ______ around it.
>   The carpenter was ______ a story about ______ a ______ to make the three sides the same length.

Answer to the above:

> angriest, granites or gantries
>  relating, altering, triangle

Pair 7:

> In a severe case of brain-drain, the ______ began ______ out of the country after ______ their STEM studies.
>   I had some trouble with ______, but the ______ part of the course for me was Diffy Qs.

Answer to the above:

> emigrants, streaming, mastering
>  integrals, gnarliest

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pair 1:

> A few beers *could* *cloud* my reasoning. The *doula* thought the baby
>  was ugly, but she didn’t say so *aloud*.

Pair 3:

> The man *mined* for gold and put the nuggets in a *denim* sack. He
>  made one too many *snide* comments, and now he *dines* alone.

Pair 6:

> The *angriest* of the quarry workers decided to block the boss’s car
>  by putting several *gantries* around it. The carpenter was *relating*
>  a story about *altering* a *triangle* to make the three sides the same
>  length.

Comment: The second word in the first sentence might be rot13(tnagevrf).

Comment: @lannyStrack V guvax lbh ner evtug. Vg jbhyq znxr zber frafr guna zl ovmneer cyhenyvmngvba yby

Comment: Anthroman and Lanny Strack are tied with 3 correct answers each, so Anthroman gets the check mark for posting first.

Answer (score 7):

#### Partial answer

Pair 4:

> The biggest *danger* in that *garden* is the thorns.
>  The lot has *angled* parking, but make sure you *dangle* a permit from your rear-view mirror.

Pair 5:

> He *resided* in the most *desired* part of town, although he could barely afford it.
>  Whenever she *decries* the slippery driveway, I go out and spread some *deicers* on it.

Pair 7:

> In a severe case of brain-drain, the *emigrants* began *streaming* out of the country after *mastering* their STEM studies.
>  I had some trouble with *integrals*, but the *gnarliest* part of the course for me was Diffy Qs.

Answer (score 4):

#### Partial answer

Pair 2:

> I used to wear polyester *knits* but they made me *stink*, so I switched to cotton.
>  The cats would *slink* around the ceramics factory, but not when the *kilns* were fired up.

Pair 3:

> The man ______ for gold and put the nuggets in a ______ sack.
>  He made one too many *Elvis* comments, and now he *lives* alone. (?)

Pair 5:

> He *resided* in the most *desired* part of town, although he could barely afford it. (?)
>  Whenever she ______ the slippery driveway, I go out and spread some ______ on it.