# Anagrammatically speaking 3

Tags: wordplay, anagram

Fill in the blanks below. Each sentence uses words that are anagrams of each other. In each pair of sentences, solve the first sentence, change one letter of an answer-word from that sentence, and shuffle it to form the answer-words for the second sentence. The answer-words in all sentences are the same length. Other than that, there is no correlation between answer-words from one sentence-pair to the next. All resulting sentences must make sense, and must use answer-words that are legal in Scrabble.

Similar earlier puzzles are here:
[Anagrammatically speaking 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97995/anagrammatically-speaking-2)
[Anagrammatically speaking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/anagrammatically-speaking)

Pair 1:

> The farmer sold one ______ before having to ______ to the barn to ______ for a cow.
>   They ______ collected trash for eight hours, and the next day they sure did ______.

Pair 2:

> The governor’s ______ had the ______ first.
>   The concert-goers were a bit ______ afterwards, but their enthusiasm for the band did not ______.

Pair 3:

> There is ______ at Barroh Harbor, where you can ______ for a fee.
>   The ______ of garbage was easily noticeable from the ______.

Pair 4:

> Laurent Renault drew a coin from his ______ as the barman drew wine from a ______.
>   The cashier took ten seconds to ______ twenty ______.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm almost there, but can anyone improve on my doubtful **Pair 4**?

**Edit:** It seems to be the first variation, I'll leave the other so the comments work.

Pair 1:

> The farmer sold one **acre** before having to **race** to the barn to **care** for a cow.
>  Change **R** to **H**.
>  They **each** collected trash for eight hours, and the next day they sure did **ache**.

Pair 2:

> The governor’s **aide** had the **idea** first.
>  Change **I** to **F**.
>  The concert-goers were a bit **deaf** afterwards, but their enthusiasm for the band did not **fade**.

Pair 3:

> There is **room** at Barroh Harbor, where you can **moor** for a fee.
>  Change **M** to **D**.
>  The **odor** of garbage was easily noticeable from the **door**.

Pair 4:

> Laurent Renault drew a coin from his **sack** as the barman drew wine from a **cask**.
>
>  Preferred) Change **K** to **N**.
>  The cashier took ten seconds to **scan** twenty **cans**.
>
>  Other) Change **K** to **E**.
>  The cashier took ten seconds to **case** twenty **aces**.

I started with Pair 2:

> **aide** – **idea** to get working with 4 letters.

I like the way OP makes anagrams of names –
Here is **Barroh Harbor** and **Laurent Renault**.
The previous puzzle had **Dolly Lloyd**.

Comment: I like 1 for 4. Nice work.

Comment: yes. The first solution under pair 4 seems correct. Well done!

Comment: Ah yes thanks: I didn't quite connect the first **cashier** with what they are doing, and my second **cashier** is supposed to be in a casino.