# Anagrammatically speaking 5

Tags: wordplay, anagram

Fill in the blanks of each sentence below with words that are anagrams of each other. In each pair of sentences, solve the first sentence, change one letter of an answer-word from that sentence, and shuffle it to form the answer-words for the second sentence. The answer-words in all sentences are the same length. Other than that, there is no correlation between answer-words from one sentence-pair to the next. All resulting sentences must make sense, and must use answer-words that are legal in Scrabble.

Similar earlier puzzles are here:
[Anagrammatically speaking 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98350/anagrammatically-speaking-4)
[Anagrammatically speaking 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98007/anagrammatically-speaking-3)
[Anagrammatically speaking 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97995/anagrammatically-speaking-2)
[Anagrammatically speaking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/anagrammatically-speaking)

Pair 1:

> There was a ______ between the two companies to see who could produce the cheaper ______.
>   The ______ habit of Leona O’Neal is to drink two ______ after dinner and then watch TV until 2am.

Pair 2:

> I am buying a gallon of ______ for me, and another gallon for ______ to my neighbor.
>   Everybody ______ that the dessert cart at the Argentine Tangerine needs ______.

Pair 3:

> If we plant crops in the spring, it gives us something to do, and it ______ the ______ problem that we could ______.
>   While the interviewer ______ the history of the missing ______, the CEO ______ by trying to ______ the story so it ______ to the audience’s sympathies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pair 1 is solved by Daniil

Pair 2

> I am buying a gallon of **SEALER** for me, and another gallon for **RESALE** to my neighbor.
>  Everybody **RELAYS** that the dessert cart at the Argentine Tangerine needs **LAYERS**.
>  A good alternative for the second part has been suggested by MacGyver88:
>  Everybody **AGREES** that the dessert cart at the Argentine Tangerine needs **GREASE**.

Pair 3

> If we plant crops in the spring, it gives us something to do, and it **AVERTS** the **VASTER** problem that we could **STARVE**.
>  While the interviewer **TRACES** the history of the missing **CRATES**, the CEO **REACTS** by trying to **RECAST** the story so it **CATERS** to the audience’s sympathies.

Comment: rot13(V'z guvaxvat NTERRF naq TERNFR sbe cneg 2 bs 2.) Maybe :)

Comment: @MacGyver88 Oh yes, that could also work

Comment: rot13(Ternfr va lbhe qrffreg?  Tebff...)

Comment: @Darrel, It's an acquired taste. :)

Comment: Since this answer is more complete than the other answer, I'm giving this one the check mark. Also, it's the dessert ***cart*** that needs _____, not the desserts themselves! I was trying to make it trickier by wording it as I did.

Answer (score 8):

Pair 1:

> There was a BATTLE between the two companies to see who could produce the cheaper TABLET.
>  The LATEST habit of Leona O’Neal is to drink two LATTES after dinner and then watch TV until 2am.