# Anagrammatically speaking 6

Tags: wordplay, anagram

Fill in the blanks of each sentence below with words that are anagrams of each other. In each pair of sentences, solve the first sentence, change one letter of an answer-word from that sentence, and shuffle it to form the answer-words for the second sentence. The answer-words in all sentences are the same length. Other than that, there is no correlation between answer-words from one sentence-pair to the next. All resulting sentences must make sense, and must use answer-words that are legal in Scrabble.

Similar earlier puzzles are here:
[Anagrammatically speaking 5](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98375/anagrammatically-speaking-5)
[Anagrammatically speaking 4](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98350/anagrammatically-speaking-4)
[Anagrammatically speaking 3](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/98007/anagrammatically-speaking-3)
[Anagrammatically speaking 2](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97995/anagrammatically-speaking-2)
[Anagrammatically speaking](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97502/anagrammatically-speaking)

Pair 1:

> You can stay an extra night for free at Torres Resort, with the ______ that you ______ by 8am.
>
> "I just spotted another ______!" the bird watcher exclaimed in an unusual ______.

Pair 2:

> The ______ was given a three-day pass, but the two ______ had to ______.
>
> At the ______, I found the plot to "Deadlier, Redialed" to be ______, because it was pretty obvious who the ______ was.

Pair 3:

> We ______ out the shark-______ tiles, since nobody wants them near their pool or bathtub.
>
> At the end of his three-hour presentation on anagrams, his voice was shot, but Reggie Geiger threw open the ______, ______ his arms, and ______, "I know a guy who monetizes timezones in the ungodliest longitudes!"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pair 1:

> You can stay an extra night for free at Torres Resort, with the **caveat** that you **vacate** by 8am.
>
>  Change one **A** to **O**.
>
>  "I just spotted another **avocet**!" the bird watcher exclaimed in an unusual **octave**.

Pair 2:

> The **marine** was given a three-day pass, but the two **airmen** had to **remain**.
>
>  Change **R** to **C**
>
>  At the **cinema**, I found the plot to "Deadlier, Redialed" to be **anemic**, because it was pretty obvious who the **Iceman** was.

Pair 3:

> I was working on this one at first but @BeastlyGerbil got there before me. I had got the second sentence only:
>
>  At the end of his three-hour presentation on anagrams, his voice was shot, but Reggie Geiger threw open the **drapes**, **spread** his arms, and **rasped**, "I know a guy who monetizes timezones in the ungodliest longitudes!"

Comment: Since this answer is more complete than the other answer, I'm giving this one the check mark.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't want to just copy from the other answer to finalise it.

Comment: @FlanMan oh this 100% should get the checkmark, I only got 1/3 of the answers, WeatherVane got *over* 2/3! Well done WeatherVane! :) (p.s. @ flanman this is my favourite one of these yet, just because of all the perfectly hidden anagrams :P)

Comment: I love the "throwaway" anagrams too.

Answer (score 5):

Solution to 3:

> We **PHASED** out the shark-**SHAPED** tiles, since nobody wants them near their pool or bathtub.
>
> Changing **H** to **R**
>
> At the end of his three-hour presentation on anagrams, his voice was shot, but Reggie Geiger threw open the **DRAPES**, **SPREAD** his arms, and **RASPED**, "I know a guy who monetizes timezones in the ungodliest longitudes!"

This also means

> The answers are of length $6$

I really like all the hidden anagrams so some bonus hidden ones:

> Torres Resort
> Deadlier, Redialed
> Reggie Geiger
> Monetizes timezones
> Ungodliest longitudes
>
> are all anagram pairs!